# JPA: generate non pk unique and random alphanumeric value

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I want to uniquely identity an entity without using the primary key. So I thought about generating an unique and random value. Moreover, value must be easy to read / manually copy and is expected to be 6 or 7 characters long.

### Design

My entity A:

```
public class A{
    // ...
    @Column(name="value", unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String value;
    // ...

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    protected void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

represented in the database by the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.mytable{
    -- ...
    value TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT generate_unique_value_for_mytable(),
    -- ...
    CONSTRAINT "un_value" UNIQUE (value),
    -- ...
}
```

I thought letting the database handling this and then fetch the value...

### Problem

With the current design, *value* is correctly generated in the database but when JPA fetches A entities, *value* field is empty.

1. I cannot remove *insertable=false* otherwise, it will hit against the *NOT NULL* constraint
2. If I remove *insertable=false* and I put some dummy data, the data overrides the value generated by *generate_unique_value_for_mytable()*
3. If I remove everything in the Column annotation, I can save the A entity but *value* is still empty

### Ugly solution

I couldn't find a proof but it looks like having the database generating a value is a bad idea. I do have the same problem for a non-primary key field which is generated by a sequence: I cannot fetch the value from the database.

So my ugly solution is to decorate the *create()* method of the EJB responsible for A entities:

```
public class Aejb{

    public void create(A entity){

        // method kind of ensures randomness
        String value = MyUtil.generateRandomValue();
        A isThereAnyoneHere = findByValue(value);

        while(isThereAnyoneHere != null){
            String value = MyUtil.generateRandomValue();
            isThereAnyoneHere = findByValue(value);
        }

        // unicity is ensured
        entity.setValue(value);

        em.persist(entity);
    }

}
```

### Questions

1. Can I fetch a non-primary key value generated by the database from a JPA entity? Value can be generated by a function or a sequence.
2. Is there a more elegant solution than my ugly workaround to provide an unique and random value?

Comment: in theory uniquely identification IS primary key

Comment: GUID / UUID have some analogies, and probably many implementations

Comment: @JacekCz Thanks for the hint. I do understand that PK is the uniqueness discriminant. But for some reason, we can't use it. And I don't know to use pseudo algorithm which derives from PK. On the other hand, the value may be manually input by users so that's why value is about 6 or 7 characters long. AFAIK, GUID and UUID are much longer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Self-answer to mark question as closed</sup>

---

### Final solution

We finally went for a combination of

- **Stored procedures**: the database will generate the value. The procedure also ensures that the value is unique across the table
- **Named queries**: to fetch the generated value by the procedure. I did not use *NamedStoredProcedures* because we are using PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL JDBC driver did not support name parameters which raised some problems.

With this configuration, the EJB is sure to have at most one database call to fetch the requested value.

### Response to other answers

Here is a summary of the other answers feedback for self-reference and next readers:

- **Oracle trigger**: we're using PostgreSQL :(
- **UUID**: We had the constraint of having our unique and random code human-readable. An end-user is assumed to be able to manually rewrite it. Consequently, we could not have a long String such as an UUID.
- **PrePersist**: Other business actions take place after the code generation in the same transaction which means that those actions need to be redone in case of collision. I'm not very confident about managing JPA exception (transaction scope and so on) so I preferred not to play with it.
- **@Generated**: This is a Hibernate specific feature. We're using EclipseLink
- **Database Trigger**: If code were purely generated at database level, I encountered the same problems of not fetching the value: the value is properly generated as database level but the entity will have the value as `null`

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.You haven't mentioned your database, but it is possible for
   Oracle to return the value inserted via triggers, and have
   Eclipselink obtain this value in your model - see
   https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm
2. Set the value using a @PrePersist method that will get executed
       before the entity is inserted, but if you are relying on one or more database queries, you will run into performance issues, as inserting a new A will be expensive. You might instead just insert the random value and deal with the occasional conflict, and pick some random that has less chance of overlaps, like a UUID.

Comment: 1. Apologies. I'm using PostgreSQL. Thanks for the hint, I didn't know *returninsert* 2. when you said "deal with the occasional conflict", do you expect to have an exception triggered and manage it or check the uniqueness beforehand (so via a query...)?

Comment: I assume you would have a unique constraint on the field, and so the insert statement itself would fail if it picks a duplicate value. This will occur on an em.flush or transaction commit though, and not directly on the 'persist' call.

Comment: For your information, I have the solution we implemented. We did not use your idea for this problem but we actually used your 2nd idea for another problem :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, @Generated annotation should do the trick. This annotation sets the value from database DEFAULT field value.

Example:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name="value", unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String value;
```

However there is a drawback: if you decide to set value of your field in Java, it would be overwritten by Hibernate using the result from DEFAULT in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately, we use EclipseLink and it appears that `@Generated` is Hibernate specific. Too bad because it sounds that this is exactly what we need

Comment: Well, sorry for misleading. 
However, I can suggest another solution, though it's not elegant. You could try making a pre-insert trigger on your table to set value of your field. Documentation on triggers:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit afraid of trigger as I know very little :) Moreover, I'm afraid that as a database-level feature, I'll be back to the same problem: JPA can fetch a value generated by the database

Comment: Just in case you decide using triggers, there is an example.
First you create a function, that returns  trigger. For you it should look something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.set_value() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF (NEW.value is null) THEN
   NEW.value:=generate_unique_value_for_mytable();
END IF;
return NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Then you create a trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER set_value_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON schema.my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.set_value();

Comment: For your information, I posted the solution we implemented. It's actually inspired from your trigger idea except that the database trigger step is replaced by an EJB call. Many thanks